# Is it possible to change ONE line in a txt file WITHOUT reading and writing the whole file (Java)?

Tags: java, file, text, replace, line

Say I have a text file:

```
I love bananas.
<age> 23 </age> years old.
I like beaches.
```

All I want to do is open said file and change the age to 24 or 25. Any way to do that in Java WITHOUT reading a writing the whole file? I know its possible with buffered reader and writer, but I am looking for a less memory intensive way when the file gets to be huge.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: It isn't possible to change 1 *line*: you can only overwrite the bytes that are already there (or add more bytes to the end of the file). You can change that line to something else which fits within the same bytes, you just can't remove the line, change its length etc.

Comment: It is possible to use random access mode if you know what you're doing.  But even if you do, it's rarely worth the effort (and risk).

Comment: Part of the purpose of streams is to not have to load an entire file into memory in order to process it but stream it by some increment such as a line or char and process it that way perhaps also by using a small cache or read-ahead techniques when necessary.  Take a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html to learn about the java 8 streams  API.  Steams can be very efficient since they pipeline data. Streams are also used for efficient XML parsing of large files, e.g. SAX.

Comment: @TrisNefzger - Streams don't solve the problem of updating a few characters in the middle of a file.

Comment: @Hot Licks - In part that is not necessarily a problem but a symptom cast as a hopeful solution to the real problem which is often excessive memory usage caused by reading an entire humongous file and which is frequently the limiting factor in what can be done with some systems such as R. Streaming solves that problem.

Comment: @TrisNefzger - Streaming makes an incredibly inefficient process slightly less inefficient.  And it has been possible, in most languages to do "streaming" for decades -- it's not a new invention.

Comment: @Hot Licks - Inneffecient in terms of what? - I guess you mean processing time. Streaming is effecient in terms of memory utilization compared to reading an entire file at once into memory and that can be an enabler for doing tasks on machines with limited memory. I have not seen anything fundamentally new in technology for decades. Streaming is not an exception to that and pointing it out is not exceptional.  To make the process more efficient in terms of processing time a standard technique is to split the large file into chunks and distribute their processing.

Comment: Inefficient compared to a random-access update.  You still read/write the entire file.  In most environments you "dirty" the disk cache for the entire file.  The ONLY thing saved is CPU RAM, which may not be the critical resource.  (In fact, in most cases disk throughput is more critical.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Hobo was correct with you can replace "23" with "99" but not 100. I was able to use this:

```
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file_paths), charset);
content = content.replaceAll(OldNumber,Integer.toString(NewNumber)); 
Files.write(file_paths, content.getBytes(charset)); // Writes it back to the file.
```

In addition there are two others methods: **Filename.utils in Apache** AND **Random File Access** Method. To find what you want to replace use .replace command!

Comment: You wanted to update file without reading whole file and here you are reading whole file to string! I mean, by not reading whole file I expect to do not have whole file in memory at once.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: no.

Long answer:
Not really. If you know that the text you're inserting directly replaces the text you're removing you could perform a substitution by seeking to the portion of the file, reading a small block, substituting the new text and replacing that block. This would work for *your* age replacement example, but not if you're replacing 9 with 10, or 99 with 100, for example.

However, there are other difficulties:

You may have variable length lines, so you don't know where to seek to. You will still have to read the file as far as the place you make the substitution, even if you do it a block at a time and discard the unwanted ones.

You have a further complexity with multi-byte character sets like UTF-8. Your ingoing text may display as the same length as your outgoing text, but may be shorter or longer depending on the substitution.

`e` (U+0065) codes as one byte, but `é` (U+00E9) codes as two.

But, if you're just looking for a less memory intensive method you can read a file one line at a time, and write each line to a new file as you process it. When you're done, delete the old file and rename the new one. This might be slow, so buffering reads and writes to, say, 20 lines (or 100, or 1000, or whatever you choose..) will improve performance.

Comment: So if in all my text files I have an 8 digit number and I have a new 8 digit number I want to replace how would I do that? Can u show some sample code?

Comment: Java's not my thing, so no, I can't offer code. In any case, if you are performing the sort of simple substitution you're suggesting the method you might best use will depend on the file size, the nature of the data and the environment. Doing this as a one-time exercise in  a Linux environment I'd probably opt to do it with `sed` and not write a program at all. Your requirement might be very different.